# MySQL: how can I replace only first char if it contains a determinate char?

Tags: mysql, string, replace

as title, I would to know how replace only the first char of a record if it contains a determinate char?

> For example:
>
> record: " hello" --> record "hello".

Here i remove the space from the string " hello"

Thanks

Comment: SOLVED: 

I found answer into mysql documents:
`mysql> SELECT TRIM(LEADING 'x' FROM 'xxxbarxxx');
        -> 'barxxx' `

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer for future perusers of this question.

Comment: you should put your answer, it is WAY BETTER than the accepted solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If YourField has a space as first character, use this.
You can, ofcourse, change the first character to whatever you like.

```
UPDATE YourTable SET
YourField = RIGHT(YourField,LENGTH(YourField)-1)
WHERE YourField like ' %'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just update "only" the first character, you have to replace the whole column using a regular update.